# Angular 2 - ngSwitch with readonly constants defined in component class

Tags: angular

I cant make this work

```
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {

    public static readonly INPUT                      = 1;
    public static readonly DROP_DOWN                  = 2;
    public static readonly DATE_RANGE                 = 3;
    public static readonly PRODUCT_INPUT              = 4;
```

If I use DataTableComponent.INPUT for instance, I get

"INPUT is not part of undefined" error

so in the template the classname is not defined

but as I remove the class name, INPUT seems undefined too

```
             <div [ngSwitch]="column.type">
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="INPUT">
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="DROP_DOWN">
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="DATE_RANGE">
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="PRODUCT_INPUT">
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                        missing column.type
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
```

how to use predefined constants in ngSwitches ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope on template expressions in Angular is the class it's related too - not static members unfortunately. If you need them to be static, you could wrap them with `getters` in your class file like this:

```
get input () {
  return DataTableComponent.INPUT;
}
```

Here is a [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xRFsx7vhlNDxD3lN0eno?p=preview) showing this approach